# Can I change the Default Alernate Access Mapping to include the domain?

Tags: 2010, alternate-access-mapping

We have two domains joined through a trust and when people access the SharePoint site in Domain A from Domain B they have to add .xyz.local to all SharePoint addresses.

For general usage this is fine but if someone is sending an email from a workflow, etc. - it does not include the .occ.local.

Can I change the the default AMM that is currently set to `http://portal` to `http://portal.xyz.local`?

What are the potential effects/problems?

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to map `http://portal.xyz.local` as the internal url in your AAM settings. I am assuming these domains are part of the same ROOT domain controller (forest) from the details shared in the question.

Comment: The 'Intranet Zone' is already set to `http://portal.xyz.local` it is whether changing the 'Default Zone' to that address would mean internally created links from workflows etc would then include the `.xyz.local` which is important for users accessing from the additional domain.

We currently have two forests that are linked with Full Trust. Each domain sits under one of the forests. We are in the process of migrating to one forest.